# How do I remove all class divs except the last 2 using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I remove all class divs except the last 2 using jquery?

I have a set of comments that show in a .comment_container class. When show all comments is clicked a list of all comments for a particular micropost is shown before the most 2 recent which show by default.

How ever if a user types a comment before clicking to see all comments this comment is added to the list and now 3 recent comments show. Because of the way I've set up some back end code it causes the least most recent comment to be shown twice when the show all link is clicked.

No need to get into the details but what I've decided to do is count the total divs and from the total remove all the divs but 2 (the last 2 in the list which are the most recent).

How can I achieve this using jquery?

Kind regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use  `slice()` (and credit to @Felix Kling for the update):

```
$(".comment_container").slice(0, -2).remove();
```

However, given your description of your problem this doesn't sound like the best course of action. It may be worth you starting a new question about the problem you have with the comments with some detail about your code.

More info on [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).

Comment: Or just `.slice(0, -2)` (after checking that more than `n` elements are selected).

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks - I never realised you could do that! Maybe I should read the docs some more!

Comment: Perfect solution for my situation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have the two last div's that you dont want to include have ID's?

I believe you could use jQuery `.not()` to remove the last two div's after you've chosen you're selector something like this

`$('.comment_container').not('#lastDiv, #lastButone')`

Then you can show all comments but not those 2.

more info on [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)